# Calling existing Web api from a Bluemix app

Tags: soap, ibm-cloud

I have a server running a SOAP Api. The API may be called over the Internet (no VPN connection required). I have created an API in Bluemix, associated a plan with it. I imported the WSDL from the URL. My assumption was that when calling the Bluemix API that is defined it would automatically proxy the call, and the proxy would call my server (that is not in the Bluemix environment). This does not seem to be happening. Is it more complicated than that? My end goal is to leverage the Bluemix dev environment, and the API management capabilities, but keep the "real" endpoint serving up web services via SOAP where it is. What am I missing?

Comment: As I understand it, Bluemix is a cloud development and runtime environment that hosts a variety of platforms and programming languages.  I think you are saying you have a SOAP/HTTP exposed service that is Internet accessible and you wish to invoke it from a Bluemix hosted application ... but what is the nature of that application?  Is it Java, JavaScript, Node-RED or something else?  What is it being hosted within .. a Node.JS container, a liberty server, a WAS server, a docker container ... I think we are going to have to know more to assist.

Comment: The service is a SOAP service that is Internet accessible. I am trying to access it via PHP, but even trying to call it from a browser (using Poster) using the displayed URL, credentials, does not work:

Comment: The service is a SOAP service that is Internet accessible (hosted outside of Bluemix). Trying to access it via PHP, but even trying to call the Bluemix service  from a browser (using Poster) using the displayed URL, credentials does not work (using the display of instantiated credentials from show credentials in the Bluemix UI). It looks like the Bluemix service never connects to the server providing the SOAP service:. What I also find curious is there seems to be no place to configure the SOAP "endpoint" where the actual call will take place. Shouldn't that be part of the service?

Comment: Your understanding of the API Management capabilities is correct. We need to figure out why the proxy is not working the way you want. Is its satus in the API management console green and do you see errors in the log?